# Sending XML data using curl

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am trying to invoke a webservice uisng curl. I am receiving "connection timed out" error while running this script. Please assist me to resolve this issue.

**Client:**

```
<?php 

    #parameters
    $strParams          = '';
    $strAPIname         = 'CordecAPI';
    $url                = 'http://86.17.13.109:81/Webbooker';

    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <SOAPENV:Envelope 
            xmlns:SOAPENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
            xmlns:SOAPENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
              <SOAPENV:Body>
                <JobRequest xmlns="http://81.105.223.86:80/cni">
                  <SourceSystem>KVCARS</SourceSystem>
                  <SourcePassword>Ketchup96</SourcePassword>
                  <SourceJobID>*KV001*</SourceJobID>
                  <SourceAccount>CORDIC</SourceAccount>
                  <TargetSystem>TARGET1</TargetSystem>
                  <Lifetime>60</Lifetime>
                  <DriverNotes>Please wait at reception.</DriverNotes>
                  <OperatorNotes>Test job for CNI.</OperatorNotes>
                  <BookerName>Jane</BookerName>
                  <BookerPhone>01954233255</BookerPhone>
                  <BookerEmail>jane.test@cordic.com</BookerEmail>
                  <StopList>
                    <Stop>
                      <Order>1</Order>
                      <Passenger>Fara Arani</Passenger>
                      <Address>Cordic Ltd, 1 Rowles Way, Swavesey, Cambridge</Address>
                      <Postcode>CB24 4UG</Postcode>
                      <ContactPhone>01954233255</ContactPhone>
                      <ContactOnArrive>Ring</ContactOnArrive>
                    </Stop>
                    <Stop>
                      <Order>2</Order>
                      <Address>Heathrow Airport, Terminal 4</Address>
                      <Postcode>TW6 3GA</Postcode>
                    </Stop>
                  </StopList>
                  <AttributeList>
                    <Attribute>Executive</Attribute>
                    <Attribute>Professional</Attribute>
                  </AttributeList>
                </JobRequest>
              </SOAPENV:Body>
            </SOAPENV:Envelope>';

            $soap_do = curl_init(); 
            curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL,            $url ); 
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1');         
            curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10); 
            curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10); 
            curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
            curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
            curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
            curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true ); 
           curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,    $xml); 
           curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length: '.strlen($xml) )); 
          //curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user . ":" . $password);

          $result = curl_exec($soap_do);
          $err = curl_error($soap_do);
          $inf = curl_getinfo($soap_do);            
          if(!$result)
             {
                echo "CURL FAIL: $url TIMEOUT=10, CURL_ERRNO=$err";
                echo PHP_EOL . '<pre>' . PHP_EOL;
                var_dump($inf);
                echo PHP_EOL . '</pre>' . PHP_EOL;
             }
          echo $result;
          echo $err;
?>
```

If you have any example in soap. Please share with me, but I am more comfortable with curl methods.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Hi, Solution resolved,

```
//curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user . ":" . $password);
```

I just put the user name and password information and its working now

## Denil:

Your comments were also helpful, thank you very much for helping. and thanks to stackoverflow Team for this portal.

Best Regards!

Ali Raza

+92 336 5141224

Answer (score 0):

You must set the header with SOAPAction: ""

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('SOAPAction: ""'));
```

Comment: can you please explain a bit ? or any example ?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383528, please check that link for the purpose of SOAPAction header. Basically the value is in uri format to indicate the intent of the message unless if the HTTP Request URL already indicated it then SOAPAction will be empty ("")

Comment: Now I have added the SOAPAction but still i see this error



$headers = array(
                        "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                        "Accept: text/xml",
                        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                        "Pragma: no-cache",
                        "SOAPAction: http://86.17.13.109:81/Webbooker", 
                        "Content-length: ".strlen($xml),
                    ); //SOAPAction: your op URL

Comment: your SOPAction url is not accessible. you need to make sure that it can be reached

Comment: Your URL redirects to a login page. Are you sure that there's a web service in that url? That may be one reason why your request is not working in the first place